# Shortened links. How to curl them? and execute bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl

In this link http://goo.gl/3WQR9M I have some example shell script code, and I want to know how put this to work:

```
bash <(curl -s http://goo.gl/3WQR9M)
```

this instead of curl the full link:
(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DiogoSaraiva/b3a1ee49a049a152cfaf/raw/a2e5329ed4f9dee964ee2fe0d25d5967b7714d76/upgrade.sh):
with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "###>  UPGRADE  <###\n"
apt-get upgrade -y
sleep 3
echo -e "\n\n"
echo -e "###>  DIST-UPGRADE  <###\n"
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sleep 3
echo -e "\n\n"
echo -e "###>  AUTOREMOVE  <###\n"
apt-get auto remove
```

just output this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Permanently</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Permanently</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DiogoSaraiva/b3a1ee49a049a152cfaf/raw/a2e5329ed4f9dee964ee2fe0d25d5967b7714d76/upgrade.sh">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

is there any --option for curl the https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DiogoSaraiva/b3a1ee49a049a152cfaf/raw/a2e5329ed4f9dee964ee2fe0d25d5967b7714d76/upgrade.sh instead of http://goo.gl/3WQR9M , but with the small one (e.g.: curl http://goo.gl/3WQR9M)

What I need is:

Upload for somewhere my script; DONE
Get the URL of the RAW? file; DONE
In a small command execute the shell script which is in the internet; HOW?

Comment: try `-L`, sounds like thats the one to follow redirects

Comment: Side note: you don't need a process substitution here. This should be enough: `curl -sL http://goo.gl/3WQR9M | bash`. If you need some arguments, use the `-s` option to `bash`: `curl -sL http://blahblah | bash -s arg1 arg2 arg3 ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curl **-L** option to follow the *Location* headers. You can then use the following shell command:

```
curl -sSL http://goo.gl/3WQR9 | sudo sh
```